# Tring to check for multiples of another number in java

Tags: java, algebra

*Before I say anything, please note I am new to java so if you have to put jargon in your answers, please tell me what it means. Thanks!*
I've been googling for an hour to see if anyone else has tried doing this. Am pretty sure I'm not the only one haha, maybe I'm just a bad googler, but I looked for libaries that emplemented this and couldn't find any, so I decided to try a way using brute force:
I used 4 to test it. It should be something like [1.0, 4.0, 2.0].
However it just returns [1.0 and 4.0]
Why? lol thanks for the help. If you need the whole program create a comment and I'll give you the github address (I'm creating a program that solves quadratic equations)

```
package quadraticResolver;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class factorisedEquation {

    public factorisedEquation() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMultiples(4))); //test
    }

    private double[] addElement(double[] array, double appendNum) {

        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
        array[array.length - 1] = appendNum;
        return array;
    }

    private double[] getMultiples(int product) {
        double[] multiples = new double[]{1, product}; //The array

        for (double i = 0.01; i < product; i = i + 0.01) {
            if ((product % i == 0) && (i != 1)) { //if Divisible by the argument product, add it to the array.
                multiples = addElement(multiples, i);
            }
        }
        return multiples; //return the new array
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read [What every programmer should know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Essentially, never compare floating point values with `==` (and `product % i` **will** produce a floating point value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use integer arithmetic everywhere to get your desired answer. Here's the corected program:

```
package quadraticResolver;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class factorisedEquation {

    public factorisedEquation() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMultiples(4))); //test
    }

    private int[] addElement(int[] array, int appendNum) {

        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
        array[array.length - 1] = appendNum;
        return array;
    }

    private int[] getMultiples(int product) {
        int[] multiples = new int[]{1}; //The array

        for (int i = 2; i <= product; i = i + 1) {
            if ((product % i == 0) && (i != 1)) { //if Divisible by the argument product, add it to the array.
                multiples = addElement(multiples, i);
            }
        }
        return multiples; //return the new array
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        factorisedEquation f = new factorisedEquation();
     }

}
```

The output: [1, 2, 4]
Ok?